# PuTTYgen couldn't load private key unable to open file

Tags: ssh, putty

I was trying to load a private key downloaded from a hosting site in PuTTYgen.
I got this error:

> PuTTYgen couldn't load private key (unable to open file)

How can I solve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that PuTTYgen had a problem loading the file from that specific location on the HD (The location had spaces and non ascii characters. Not sure which caused the exact issue).

Moving it to a different directory (i.e. Desktop) solved the issue.

Comment: The solution to spaces in folder+filename is to put brackets before the disk/folder and put another one at the end of the filename extension: `"C:\folder 1\file.txt"`